# OpenCL no GPUs found

Tags: rendering

I'm using 2.8 recently but i have no gpus found for opencl settings.[image]

Comment: ı have no AMD, i use Nvidia rtx2070

Comment: Is there any reason that you need to use OpenCL than CUDA? Nvidia card can only use CUDA option in Blender for now.

Comment: i donno, i just got my pc is forced and think thats the cause.

Comment: You can only use CUDA with an Nvidia GPU. OpenCL is for AMD graphics cards. Check in the CUDA tab if you want to enabled GPU rendering.